# How to make TextField's label wont move when out of focus in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter.

I'm trying to replicate the following UI, it has multiple TextField and all of their labels won't maximize when I click on other TextField, they keep on focus to show the content inside it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lUeV.png

The UI I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Rpj.png

I tried the autofocus: on but it didn't work cuz it only work for one TextField at a time.

My code:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_sample/models/user.dart';

class EmployeeProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmployeeProfile({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  final User user;

  @override
  _EmployeeProfileState createState() => _EmployeeProfileState();
}

class _EmployeeProfileState extends State<EmployeeProfile> {

  late String name = '';
  late String email = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blue])),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3
          ),
          Card(
              elevation: 20.0,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                ),
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 100.0),
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        name = val;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        labelText: 'Employee Name',
                        hintText: widget.user.name,
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144), width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    width: 150.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        email = val;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        labelText: 'Employee Email',
                        hintText: widget.user.email,
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144), width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    width: 150.0,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        print(widget.user.name);
                        print(widget.user.email);
                        setState(() {
                          widget.user.name = name;
                          widget.user.email = email;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('Save'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: AppBar(// Add AppBar here only
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Text(
                widget.user.name.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 0.0,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

P/s: sr im not really good at English to describe it correctly

Comment: Did you want the label always be visible?

Comment: Yes, I want the label always on the border, it won't move down from the border even if i interact with other TextField.

Comment: If `TextField` is empty and you out of focus it, the label will be hidden and `hint` will be visible. What you see on the `TextField` is `hint`, not moving down `label`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Label will be visible if you focus on the `TextField` or `TextField` has content. If what you mean is keeping the label always be visible, you can add `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always` on `InputDecoration`.

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_sample/models/user.dart';

class EmployeeProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmployeeProfile({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  final User user;

  @override
  _EmployeeProfileState createState() => _EmployeeProfileState();
}

class _EmployeeProfileState extends State<EmployeeProfile> {

  late String name = '';
  late String email = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blue])),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3
          ),
          Card(
              elevation: 20.0,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                ),
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 100.0),
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        name = val;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        labelText: 'Employee Name',
                        hintText: widget.user.name,
                        // add here
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always 
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144), width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    width: 150.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        email = val;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        labelText: 'Employee Email',
                        hintText: widget.user.email,
                        // add here
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144), width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    width: 150.0,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        print(widget.user.name);
                        print(widget.user.email);
                        setState(() {
                          widget.user.name = name;
                          widget.user.email = email;
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Text('Save'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: AppBar(// Add AppBar here only
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Text(
                widget.user.name.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 0.0,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. add your ListView() inside Padding

```
    Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    labelText: 'Employee Name',
                    hintText: 'widget.user.name',
                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                          width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                width: 150.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    labelText: 'Employee Email',
                    hintText: 'widget.user.email',
                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 106, 144),
                          width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                width: 150.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('Save'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Your Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help, but i want the both TextFields to look like this https://ibb.co/DM4jsNW, the content won't hide behind labelText when one of them on focus. Sorry if I'm wrong if those in the picture are not TextField

Comment: @Kronkdark if your problem has been solved by my answer please mark(Tick) it Thanks